# I tried to make a simple calculator on Swift, but it keeps saying nil

Tags: swift, calculator

I need help making a simple calculator. No UI, just typing on the console. I tried everything that I saw on the internet and lots of documentation but still can't fix it.

Note: I'm new to all of this and I'm still learning.

I tried to do this:

```
print("Please enter a mathematical equation\n(ex. 1+2, 1-2, 1*2, 1/2, (1+2)-3, 1^2)\n")

 if let response = readLine() {
    print("Your math equation is:",response)
    
    let answer = Double(response)
    print("The answer is:",answer) 
 }
```

Didn't work.

I expected it to work like this:

```
Please enter a mathematical equation
(ex. 1+2, 1-2, 1*2, 1/2, (1+2)-3, 1^2)

1+2
Your math equation is: 1+2
The answer is: 3
```

but it just said:

```
Please enter a mathematical equation
(ex. 1+2, 1-2, 1*2, 1/2, (1+2)-3, 1^2)

1+2
Your math equation is: 1+2
The answer is: nil
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the mathematical expression you receive as input is a string. First, you need to evaluate this string before you can calculate the value for the mathematical expression it represents.

For this purpose, you can use the [`expressionValue()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1410363-expressionvalue) function from the [`NSExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression) class.

Here is a simple function for this purpose:

```swift
import Foundation

func evaluateMathExpression(_ expression: String) -> Double? {
    let nsExpression = NSExpression(format: expression)
    return nsExpression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? Double
}
```

Then you can modify your existing code to use this function:

```swift
print("Please enter a mathematical equation\n(ex. 1+2, 1-2, 1*2, 1/2, (1+2)-3, 1^2)\n")

if let response = readLine() {
    print("Your math equation is:", response)
    
    let answer = evaluateMathExpression(response)
    print("The answer is:", answer) 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see that you’re trying to evaluate a mathematical expression entered by the user. However, the code you’ve written is trying to convert the user’s input directly into a Double, which will not work for mathematical expressions like “1+2”.

Swift doesn’t have built-in support for evaluating mathematical expressions. You would need to parse the expression and perform the operations yourself, or use a third-party library that can do this.

Here’s an example of how you can add two numbers:

```
import Foundation
print("Enter first number:")
let num1 = Double(readLine() ?? "") ?? 0

print("Enter second number:")
let num2 = Double(readLine() ?? "") ?? 0

let sum = num1 + num2
print("The sum is: \(sum)")
```

In this code:

We ask the user to enter the first and second numbers.
We use readLine() to read the user’s input. This function returns an optional string, so we use ?? "" to provide a default value of an empty string if the user doesn’t enter anything.
We then try to convert this string to a Double using Double(...). This also returns an optional, so we use ?? 0 to provide a default value of 0 if the conversion fails.
Finally, we add the two numbers together and print the result.
Please note that this code does not handle invalid input gracefully. If you want to improve it, you could add error checking to ensure that the user enters valid numbers. If you want to support full mathematical expressions (like “1+2*3”), you’ll need a more complex parser or a third-party library.